# How to make image on all divs at the same place

Tags: html, css

```css
html {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

body {margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-top:30px;
}

#third, fifth {
    background-color:#E8E8E8 ;
}
 
img[src^="my_menu.png"] {
    z-index:10;
}
 
#second, #third, #fourth, #fifth {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:white;
    z-index:-1;
} 

#second {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:100vh;
}

#fourth, #second {
      background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add gospel Přerov</title>
        
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div id="second">     
          </div> 
           
          <div id="third">      
          </div> 
              
          <div id="fourth">
          </div>
              
          <div id="fift">
          </div>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am making a website for my client, and I need help. I want to make 4 divs with height of `100vh`, and with width equals to `100%`. That's what I have. Now, I need to put arrow facing down to all of these divs, somewhere at the bottom center. How to do it?

Comment: Please post some relevant code we could work with, or even better - provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but according to your question, this might be what you want to achieve. Just created a `div` with an image inside (you can also use `background` property for arrow image)

```css
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.full {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.full:nth-child(1) {
  background: cyan;
}
.full:nth-child(2) {
  background: magenta;
}
.full:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}
.full:nth-child(4) {
  background: lightgray;
}
.arrow-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  left: calc(50% - 16px);
}
.arrow-down > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div class="arrow-down">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png" alt="arrow-down">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="full">
  <div class="arrow-down">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png" alt="arrow-down">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="full">
  <div class="arrow-down">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png" alt="arrow-down">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="full">
  <div class="arrow-down">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png" alt="arrow-down">
  </div>
</div>
```